# samples/bpf/xdpsock_user.c:xsk_configure_socket:331: errno: 1/"Operation not permitted"

Tags: linux, networking, ebpf, xdp-bpf

I have a similar issue to [XDP program ip link error: Prog section rejected: Operation not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60322147/xdp-program-ip-link-error-prog-section-rejected-operation-not-permitted), except on Linux 5.4.0.

I am able to run some XDP eBPF programs, but not AF_XDP:

```
➜ uname -r
5.4.0
```

```
➜ sudo strace -e bpf ./xdpsock -i eth0 -t -q1 -F
bpf(BPF_PROG_GET_FD_BY_ID, {prog_id=35, next_id=0}, 112) = 4
bpf(BPF_OBJ_GET_INFO_BY_FD, {info={bpf_fd=4, info_len=208, info=0xptr}}, 112) = 0
bpf(BPF_OBJ_GET_INFO_BY_FD, {info={bpf_fd=4, info_len=208, info=0xptr}}, 112) = 0
bpf(BPF_MAP_GET_FD_BY_ID, {map_id=35, next_id=0}, 112) = 5
bpf(BPF_OBJ_GET_INFO_BY_FD, {info={bpf_fd=5, info_len=80, info=0xptr}}, 112) = 0
bpf(BPF_MAP_UPDATE_ELEM, {map_fd=5, key=0xkeyptr, value=0xvalptr, flags=BPF_ANY}, 112) = -1 E2BIG (Argument list too long)
bpf(BPF_MAP_DELETE_ELEM, {map_fd=5, key=0xkeyptr}, 112) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
samples/bpf/xdpsock_user.c:xsk_configure_socket:331: errno: 1/"Operation not permitted"
program on interface changed, not removing
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

However, the rxq_info sample program does work:

```
➜ sudo strace -e bpf ./xdp_rxq_info -d eth0 -F
bpf(BPF_PROG_LOAD, {prog_type=BPF_PROG_TYPE_SOCKET_FILTER, insn_cnt=2, insns=0xptr, license="GPL", log_level=0, log_size=0, log_buf=0, kern_version=0, prog_flags=0}, 1
12) = 4
bpf(BPF_PROG_LOAD, {prog_type=BPF_PROG_TYPE_SOCKET_FILTER, insn_cnt=2, insns=0xptr, license="GPL", log_level=0, log_size=0, log_buf=0, kern_version=0, prog_flags=0, ..
.}, 112) = 4
bpf(BPF_MAP_CREATE, {map_type=BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY, key_size=4, value_size=32, max_entries=1, map_flags=0, inner_map_fd=0}, 112) = 4
bpf(BPF_PROG_LOAD, {prog_type=BPF_PROG_TYPE_SOCKET_FILTER, insn_cnt=5, insns=0xptr, license="GPL", log_level=0, log_size=0, log_buf=0, kern_version=0, prog_flags=0}, 1
12) = 5
bpf(0x12 /* BPF_??? */, 0xptr, 112) = 4
bpf(0x12 /* BPF_??? */, 0xptr, 112) = 4
bpf(BPF_MAP_CREATE, {map_type=BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY, key_size=4, value_size=12, max_entries=1, map_flags=0, inner_map_fd=0, ...}, 112) = 3
bpf(BPF_MAP_CREATE, {map_type=BPF_MAP_TYPE_PERCPU_ARRAY, key_size=4, value_size=16, max_entries=1, map_flags=0, inner_map_fd=0, ...}, 112) = 4
bpf(BPF_MAP_CREATE, {map_type=BPF_MAP_TYPE_PERCPU_ARRAY, key_size=4, value_size=16, max_entries=65, map_flags=0, inner_map_fd=0, ...}, 112) = 5
bpf(BPF_PROG_LOAD, {prog_type=BPF_PROG_TYPE_XDP, insn_cnt=81, insns=0xptr, license="GPL", log_level=0, log_size=0, log_buf=0, kern_version=0, prog_flags=0, ...}, 112)
= 6
bpf(BPF_MAP_UPDATE_ELEM, {map_fd=3, key=0xptr, value=0xptr, flags=BPF_ANY}, 112) = 0
bpf(BPF_OBJ_GET_INFO_BY_FD, {info={bpf_fd=6, info_len=208, info=0xptr}}, 112) = 0
bpf(BPF_MAP_LOOKUP_ELEM, {map_fd=4, key=0xptr, value=0xptr}, 112) = 0
```

and XDP is enabled (otherwise the rxq_info sample program would not work):

```
➜ grep XDP /boot/config-`uname -r`
CONFIG_XDP_SOCKETS=y
CONFIG_XDP_SOCKETS_DIAG=y
```

The call that fails is here: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/tools/lib/bpf/xsk.c#L475. Why does running xdpsock cause an error?

Comment: `E2BIG`, looks like on kernel side you're hitting [this](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/kernel/bpf/xskmap.c#L227). Are you trying to update an entry in the map at an index that would be higher that the number of entries in your map?

Comment: Yes, you're right - only queue 0 works, despite ethool reporting 8 queues.

Comment: Hmm not sure if related, did you have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60603415/af-xdp-no-packets-for-socket-with-queue-id-0-even-though-every-packet-is-redire), in case it helps?

Comment: That post discusses receiving from multiple NIC queues - in my case, I am unable to get samples/bpf/xdpsock to *bind* to a NIC queue other than 0 (otherwise resulting in the E2BIG above).